# iterate parent li using each function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my test HTML code:

```
<ul class="content">
<li class="data">
test1
    <ul>
        <li class="data">t1</li>
        <li class="data">t2</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="data">
test2
    <ul>
        <li class="data">t3</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="data">
test3
    <ul>
        <li class="data">t4</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

jquery code is:

```
$(".content li").each(function(index, element) {
    console.log(element);
});
```

In this function, all the li lists having class 'data' under the main ul.
But I need to iterate only the 3 parent li lists. How can I modify this jquery? 
Kindly help me :)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use [child selecter](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) `>` like,

```
$(".content > li").each(function(index, element) {
    console.log(element);
});
```

Comment: answer fine, but you should elaborate more about `>`

Answer (score 3):

in your jquery selector, add a `>` between .content and li..

```
$(".content > li").each(function (index, element) {
    console.log(element);
});
```

`>` looks for immediate child instead of all childs

Answer (score 0):

You can even use `.children` like bellow

```
$(".content").children('li').each(function(index, element) {
    console.log(element);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/C7JJM/59/)